# Mongoose ValidationError at server starting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a model as following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

And I use following code to connect to the db:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DBCONNECTIONSTR, { promiseLibrary: bluebird }).then(() => console.log('connection successful')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But I get the following validation error after the server is started. It has no error at all when save a record :

```
(node:17708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: name: Path `name` is required., password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required.
    at new ValidationError (/Users/bochenlin/dev/data.shojo.live/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:27:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (/Users/bochenlin/dev/data.shojo.live/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1755:32)
    at /Users/bochenlin/dev/data.shojo.live/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1627:17
    at /Users/bochenlin/dev/data.shojo.live/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:808:9
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:112:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:692:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please share DBCONNECTIONSTR

Comment: Somewhere your query has been run in the code or the function in which query has been written will be executed... Please show some more code...

Comment: The connection string is as simple as DBCONNECTIONSTR=mongodb://localhost:27017/demo

Comment: Ashish was right, thanks. Deep in the import chain, there was some "insert" tried to create dummy records for testing in a class's construction function.